# Front end login redirect to {page_url} with structure, how to make this work

Tags: structure, login, redirects, member-management

EE 2.7.2
Structure 3.3.13

I've got a site where I have a front end login form that is on all pages as a modal when clicking the login link in the header. Everything works fine, however for the redirect="" parameter I would like the form to redirect to the page it was filled out on.

using this code:

```
  {exp:member:login_form return="{page_url}"}
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="32" size="25">

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="32" size="25">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button small">
  {/exp:member:login_form}
```

results in a broken url http://domain.com/%7Bpage_url%7D

and a white page with this message

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

I tried using low variables and preparsing the {page_url} (same as embedding a template) but that also did not work.

Is there a way to get the {page_url} to work in the login form?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out, Sean?

Comment: Yes - when I can access that site, I'll look at the code and post it here as an answer. Forgot about this.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Structure global variable](http://www.buildwithstructure.com/tags/global_variables/) `{structure:page:uri}` which is the same as EE's native "page_url" variable.

Comment: tried that still getting the same error and broken url

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's just not parsing your {page_url} -- try parse="inward"?

```
{exp:member:login_form return="{page_url}" parse="inward"}
```

Comment: no change when adding parse="inward"

Answer (score 0):

Try using EE's [`{current_url}`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-url) Standard Global Variable. I've successfully used this for the return parameter on the Member module login_form tag for exactly the same scenario you are describing.

```
{exp:member:login_form return="{current_url}"}
   ...
{/exp:member:login_form}
```

Comment: Getting the same broken url... http://domain.com/%7Bcurrent_url%7D

Comment: Does `{current_url}` parse for you when output plainly in your template (ie, not as a module parameter)?